# VB Create .conf dont exist or read XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm putting together a program in VB 2008, but it doesn't have app.conf to create variables that I can modify.

I can't add an app.conf because it doesn't appear in templates (already probe)

My question is, what other solution can there be?

Could you create an XML, put the keys and call it from my form? How?

Comment: I don't have VS 2008 around to test but I find it hard to believe that it couldn't generate config files. The file is named "app.config", not "app.conf". In current VS versions, the item template is named "Application Configuration File" To the best of my knowledge, it was the same back in 2008. If you really can't add one that way, go into the project properties and add an item to the `Settings` page. That should automatically add a config file. You can then remove the setting to leave the file empty, if that's the best course of action.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using VS 2008? There are some valid reasons but, if possible, I would suggest upgrading to VS 2019 Community, which has far more features and compatibility while still being free.